# RewriteCond and RewriteRule work fine except when not using paths

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have a new domain, that needs to load the contents of an old domain via Proxy in Apache. This is already working fine:

```
<VirtualHost myserver:80>
ServerName newdomain.com
ServerAlias www.newdomain.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newdomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://olddomain.com/$1 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

For example:

- `newdomain.com/contact` loads `olddomain.com/contact`
- `newdomain.com/catalogue/342` loads `olddomain.com/catalogue/342`

But the problem comes when I try this:

- `newdomain.com` (without any additional paths). The result is a 404 error.

I pretty much guess that the issue is in the `RewriteCond` / `RewriteRule` definitions, but I can't seem to find the problem. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are these the only proxy directives you have? Note that these are from vHost:80, what about vHost:443?

Comment: @MrWhite SSL is handled exclusively through Cloudflare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://olddomain.com/$1 [P]
> ```

Because this rule is defined in a *virtualhost* context, the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against is root-relative and starts with a slash. Since this is captured and used in the *substitution* string it will result in a double slash at the start of the target URL-path.

Maybe this is throwing off the routing for the homepage.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://olddomain.com/$1 [P]
```

There's also no need for the preceding `RewriteCond` directive since you are already in the vHost for `newdomain.com` and the current *condition* omits `www.newdomain.com`, which is presumably not the intention.

---

Or don't use mod_rewrite at all, since it would seem to be a direct one-to-one proxy.

For example, use the following instead.

```
ProxyPass / https://olddomain.com/
ProxyPassReverse / https://olddomain.com/
```

Comment: I might try the second solution later, but the first solution you posted does the trick. Thanks!